# Design model that would allow DB queries but would be independent on DB provider used

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We currently use Entity Framework to access our DB. We had one large class, thousands of rows long, full of methods that queried database.

```
    void saveFirstThing() {
        using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext()) {
             ...
        }
    }

    AnotherThing returnAnotherThing() {
        using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext()) {
             ...
        }
    }
    ...
```

But if we wanted to change database provider (or test our application by using fake values), it would be pretty annoying to do. So I created:

- interface `IRepository<T>`, which provides actions with `T` - `Get(int id)`, `Add(T entity)`, `GetAll()`, ...
- Implementation of the interface, that implemented the methods by calling EF and returning IQueryable.

```
   public class AnotherThingRepository : IRepository<AnotherThing> {
        ...
        public IQueryable GetAll() {
             ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

```
    public class Something {
         AnotherThing returnAnotherThing() {
              return anotherThingRepository.GetAll().Where(...).Single();
         }
    }
```

However, I have a problem. We have methods that require joins over multiple tables. So I cannot use `using(dbContext)` inside implementation of `IRepository`, since it would drop `dbContext` before we finish querying the result (of type `IQueryable`). I cannot return `IEnumerable` or `List`, since it won't load all joined fields (and there might be lot of them). If I wanted to do some messy reflection, it would be slow and full of circular references that I would need to solve.

What is the best solution? The only thing that works now is keeping `dbContext` forever, and share it for all queries in given repository implementation. However it stops working when I need to update something from DB, since `dbContext` caches everything and dbContext shouldn't be used in a way how I'm using it right now regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing that works now is keeping dbContext forever, and share it for all queries in given repository implementation.

No.  The DbContext should be scoped to the Unit-of-Work, which might span involve multiple repository instances.

A simple implementation would inject the DbContext in the constructor of each of your repository types. eg

```
using (var db = new MyDatabase())
{
   var things = new ThingRepository(db);
   var anotherThings = new AnotherThingRepository(db);

   . . .

   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked flawlessly, and it didn't even took that long to implement.